# EC2 Ubuntu Apache keeps Connecting

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to setup an Apache server on an Ubuntu EC2 instance. I'm using 12.04 LTS, and I've tried with 14.04 LTS, but haven't reached a solution. I've scoured the internet looking for a solution but haven't found anything. My Apache settings are default and I've created a Security Group for HTTP. I also have an elastic IP associated with the instance.

When I load localhost using Lynx, I'm getting the Apache page. I cannot access it from my browser externally. The page keeps trying to connect and is waiting for it. When I nmap port 80 internally from the server, it says open. The weird thing is when I try to nmap the server from outside. It sometimes shows it's open and sometimes it shows it's down. I cannot determine the situation that causes this. It seems arbitrary to me at the moment. I've tried to launch different instances and I'm getting the same behavior. I've turned off ufw, and cleared iptables.

I am able to SSH and FTP to the server without any problems. I'm stumped, and very confused why something so simple can not work. Apache error logs are normal. I also tried with nginx and I'm getting the same problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: When you type the url in the browser, do you explicitly put `http://` in front of the Elastic IP? Some browsers will default to https if you don't specify it (which is port 443).

Comment: Yes, I've tried http://

Comment: Did you try from a different browser or a different computer?

Comment: Yes, two browsers, my cellphone and another computer.

Comment: Strange, I've installed Apache many times in Unbuntu 12.04 on EC2 and never had any issue. Can you show your Security Group config? Is HTTP restricted by Source?

Comment: Inbound it's set to http and 0.0.0.0/0. Outbound all traffic is set to 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: Did you install Apache using apt-get?

Comment: Yes. Installed through apt-get

Comment: Did you try to access it using the Public DNS instead of the Elastic IP?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that as well. I've tried the original IP, an elastic IP and the public DNS.

Comment: Ok, now I'm stumped too..